# Decorator design pattern: why call functions in chain but not in loop?

Tags: java, c++, oop, design-patterns, decorator

In decorator design pattern we wrap the same type of object in each other then in chain call the same function of them. This allows to add a functionality. Now why don't we do the same thing not in chain but in loop. I mean we can store all the objects in a vector (map?) and if a function is called we can delegate that call to each element of the vector. Buy doing this we will have even advantage such as if I would like to access (to get state of) a specific decorator I can access it directly and not add a public function to the interface so that all the decorators should override but in most of them that function should do nothing. For example, in the classic example with [windows and scrollbars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) if I wan't to know if the horizontal scroll bar is locked then I need to add isHorizontalScrollBarLocked function to `WindowDecorator`, which makes no sense for vertical scroll bar and many other decorators too.

EDIT (adding code to make clear what I say):

```
// the Window interface class
public interface Window {
    public void draw(); // draws the Window
    public String getDescription(); // returns a description of the Window
}

// extension of a simple Window without any scrollbars
class SimpleWindow implements Window {
    public void draw() {
        // draw window
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return "simple window";
    }
}

// abstract decorator class - note that it implements Window
abstract class WindowDecorator implements Window {
protected Window decoratedWindow; // the Window being decorated

public WindowDecorator (Window decoratedWindow) {
    this.decoratedWindow = decoratedWindow;
}
public void draw() {
    decoratedWindow.draw(); //delegation
}
public String getDescription() {
    return decoratedWindow.getDescription(); //delegation
    }
}



// the first concrete decorator which adds vertical scrollbar functionality
class VerticalScrollBarDecorator extends WindowDecorator {
public VerticalScrollBarDecorator (Window decoratedWindow) {
    super(decoratedWindow);
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    super.draw();
    drawVerticalScrollBar();
}

private void drawVerticalScrollBar() {
    // draw the vertical scrollbar
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
    return super.getDescription() + ", including vertical scrollbars";
}
}


// the second concrete decorator which adds horizontal scrollbar functionality
class HorizontalScrollBarDecorator extends WindowDecorator {
    public HorizontalScrollBarDecorator (Window decoratedWindow) {
        super(decoratedWindow);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        super.draw();
        drawHorizontalScrollBar();
    }

    private void drawHorizontalScrollBar() {
        // draw the horizontal scrollbar
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return super.getDescription() + ", including horizontal scrollbars";
    }
}

public class DecoratedWindowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a decorated Window with horizontal and vertical scrollbars
        Window decoratedWindow = new HorizontalScrollBarDecorator (
                new VerticalScrollBarDecorator (new SimpleWindow()));

        // print the Window's description
        System.out.println(decoratedWindow.getDescription());
    }
}
```

Now I want to know if horizontal scroll bar is locked for `decoratedWindow`. What I should do? I need to add `isHorizontalScrollBarLocked` public function in `Window` and override it in  `HorizontalScrollBarDecorator` and in all other classes that implement `Window` (in `VerticalScrollBarDecorator` `WindowDecorator`) right?

On the other hand I could create a facade, which will represent my Window. In that facade I will have a list of `Window` objects and those objects will be `SimpleWindow`, `VerticalScrollBarDecorator`, `HorizontalScrollBarDecorator`, etc. And if user will call a function `draw` of the facade, I will call in a loop all `draw` functions of `Window`s in the list. Otherwise if the user will call `isHorizontalScrollBarLocked` only on the `HorizontalScrollBarDecorator` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested change to the decorator pattern wont hold good. The facade that you want to implement does not really 'decorate' any functionality so to speak. Let me explain...

Consider a scenario where you want to use a `BufferedWriter` to write bytes into an output stream. The `BufferedWriter`'s responsibility is to wait for enough bytes to accumulate before it performs its expensive operation - writing IO. It `decorates` a normal stream by clubbing several write operations into batches.

If you had a facade which delegates calls all the way down the decorator chain, what would be the use of a `BufferedWriter` ? The facade does not really know what state the `BufferedWriter` is in so it cannot take a call on whether to execute the chain all the way down.

Comment: Facade can get the state of `BufferedWriter` as far as it is in the vector. Facade aggregates the `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: We're talking about interfaces here. You cannot provide an interface method that can communicate the state of all implementations. Why should the facade even know about the internal state of its implementations or its behavior ? Handling implementation state in a single facade is impossible.

Comment: Actually I agree with you! My question is more like why Decorater, we could use Facade. But those are different patters. In Decorator pattern the decorator interact without other ones control. Whereas Facade controls them. So you are right!